# Vitest doesn't react onClick after submit on form

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-test-utils, vitest

When test runs, it clicks on the submit button goes to handleSubmit() (when I `console.log` from there it works) as you can see values in the terminal picture.

But usernameError never renders so it cant check the value of the error message
[image]

```
{
  "name": "wwht",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .ts,.tsx,.vue src",
    "test": "vitest --dom"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.3",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.4",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "pinia": "^2.1.6",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primevue": "^3.31.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^9.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vitest": "^0.34.2",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.5"
  }
}
```

component

```
<template>
  <div class="card p-fluid">
    <form class="p-grid p-dir-col p-gap-2" data-test="registration__form">
      <span class="p-float-label">
        <InputText
          id="username"
          v-model="formData.username"
          data-test="registration__input--username"
          type="text"
        />
        <label for="username">Username</label>
      </span>
      <InlineMessage
        v-if="submitted && v$.$errors.length"
        data-test="registration__input-error--username"
        severity="error"
      >
        <div v-for="error in v$.$errors" :key="error.$uid">
          {{ error.$message }} -- {{ submitted }} -- // --
          {{ v$.$errors.length }}
        </div>
      </InlineMessage>
      <div class="p-col">
        <Button
          label="Submit"
          data-test="registration__submit--button"
          @click="handleSubmit"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, reactive, ref } from 'vue'
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core'
import { alphaNum, maxLength, minLength, required } from '@vuelidate/validators'
// import axios from 'axios'
// const apiBaseUrl = inject('apiBaseUrl') as string

const formData = reactive({
  username: '',
})

const submitted = ref(false)

const rules = computed(() => ({
  username: {
    required,
    minLength: minLength(3),
    maxLength: maxLength(20),
    alphaNum: alphaNum,
  },
}))

const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, formData) as any

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const result: boolean = await v$.value.$validate()
  if (result) {
    submitted.value = false
    return 'success'
  } else {
    submitted.value = true
    console.log(v$.value.$errors.length, submitted.value)
    return 'failure'
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

tests

```
import { afterEach, beforeEach, describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import { mount, VueWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils'
import RegistrationForm from '@/components/RegisterForm.vue'

import Button from 'primevue/button'
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config'
import InlineMessage from 'primevue/inlinemessage'

let wrapper: VueWrapper

describe('Registration form', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    wrapper = mount(RegistrationForm, {
      global: {
        plugins: [PrimeVue],
        components: {
          Button,
          InputText,
          InlineMessage,
        },
      },
    })
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
  })

  it('Registration form COMPONENT renders', () => {
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)
  })

  describe('Form ELEMENT', () => {
    it('Renders form element', () => {
      const form = wrapper.find('[data-test="registration__form"]')
      expect(form.exists()).toBe(true)
    })
    it('Form ELEMENT has button', () => {
      const button = wrapper.find('[data-test="registration__submit--button"]')
      expect(button.exists()).toBe(true)
    })

    describe('Username INPUT', () => {
      // TODO - why any?
      let registrationSubmitButton: any
      let usernameInput: any
      let usernameError: any

      beforeEach(async () => {
        registrationSubmitButton = wrapper.find(
          '[data-test="registration__submit--button"]',
        )
        usernameInput = wrapper.find(
          '[data-test="registration__input--username"]',
        )
      })
      it('Form ELEMENT includes username input', () => {
        expect(usernameInput.exists()).toBe(true)
      })

      it('Form ELEMENT includes registration submit button', () => {
        expect(registrationSubmitButton.exists()).toBe(true)
      })

      it('Username INPUT should be empty in default state', async () => {
        await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
        expect((usernameInput.element as HTMLInputElement).value).toBe('')
      })

      it('Form ELEMENT includes Error message for username input', async () => {
        registrationSubmitButton.trigger('click')
        await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
        const usernameError = wrapper.find(
          '[data-test="registration__input-error--username"]',
        )

        console.log('-----USERNAME-----', usernameError)
        console.log(wrapper.find('[data-test="registration__form"]').html())
        await expect(usernameError.exists()).toBe(true)
      })

      it('Username INPUT should have minimum length of 3 characters', async () => {
        await usernameInput.setValue('ab')
        expect((usernameInput.element as HTMLInputElement).value).toBe('ab')

        await registrationSubmitButton.trigger('click')
        await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
        await expect(usernameInput.exists()).toBe(true)
        await expect(usernameError.text()).toBe(
          'This field should be at least 3 characters long',
        )
      })

      it('Username INPUT should have maximum length of 20 characters', async () => {
        await usernameInput.setValue('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQRSTUV')
        await registrationSubmitButton.trigger('click')
        await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
        expect((usernameInput.element as HTMLInputElement).value).toBe(
          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQRSTUV',
        )
        console.log('usernameError.text()', usernameError.text())
        expect(usernameError.text()).toBe(
          'Username cannot have more than 20 characters',
        )
      })

      it('Username INPUT should be alphabetical or aplhanumerical string', async () => {
        await usernameInput.setValue('Input@Field')
        await registrationSubmitButton.trigger('click')
        await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
        expect((usernameInput.element as HTMLInputElement).value).toBe(
          'Input@Field',
        )
        expect(usernameError.text()).toBe(
          'Username must start and end with a letter and can only contain alphanumeric characters',
        )
      })

      afterEach(async () => {
        await usernameInput.setValue('')
        await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
      })
    })
  })
})
```